# Add custom menu item type

Tags: plugins, menus

Is there a way to add custom menu type to the menu editor? I know I can add items dynamically with the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` filter, but I would like to have the position of those items configurable.

Answer (score 1):

I decided for now, I will use a custom css class and detect it in a `wp_get_nav_menu_items` filter. From there, I can get the data I need to set the URL.